# VBA: Read outlook calendar - not reading recurring appointments?

Tags: vba, calendar, outlook

I'm reading the outlook calendar. Using the method I've researched on this site:

```
Dim oOL As New Outlook.Application
Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oAppointments As Object
Dim oAppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Set oNS = oOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oAppointments = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

For Each oAppointmentItem In oAppointments.Items

    DoEvents
    ' Something here
Next

Set oAppointmentItem = Nothing
Set oAppointments = Nothing
Set oNS = Nothing
Set oOL = Nothing
```

I've noticed that it does not pull in outlook recurring appointments that I have accepted in my calendar. Is this expected behavior? If not, I'll tear apart the code and try something else.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve all Outlook appointment items from the folder, you need to sort the items in ascending order and set the [IncludeRecurrences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866969.aspx) to true. You will not catch recurrent appointments if you don’t do this before!

```
 For Each oAppointmentItem In oAppointments.Items
    DoEvents
   ' Something here
 Next
```

The folder may contains a lot of calendar items. So, I'd suggest using the Find/FindNext or Restrict methods of the Items class to get items for the specified date instead. You can read more about these methods in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

Comment: Sweet. Thank you for the help. That part is now working.